# JavaScriptでタグを含む要素が返ってくる

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
const base = document.getElementById('parent');
const children = base.children;

console.log(children[0]);
console.log(children[1]);
console.log(children[2]);
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下に記述したHTMLの `<ul>` の子要素を取得するために上記のように記述しました。この場合、添付画像のようなタグを含めた要素が返ってきます。タグの中に書かれた内容を取得するにはtextContentを使えば良いようです。

初心者なもので、
<タグを含めた要素を取得してどんな使い道があるのでしょうか？
意味がよくわかりません。

使い慣れた方、これの使い道を教えてください。宜しくお願いいたします。

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

文字列が返されるわけではなく、[`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)というオブジェクトが返されています。オブジェクトなので、例えば`tagName`プロパティを持っておりその値は`"LI"`となっているはずです。このオブジェクトを`console.log()`で文字列化する際に`outerHTML`の内容が出力されたに過ぎません。

Answer (score 1):

例としている`<ul>`はメモリ上では以下のようなツリー構造になり、`<ul>`の子供はテキストではありません。

```
HTMLUListElement
 ┣ HTMLLIElement
 ┃  ┗ Text "1番目"
 ┣ HTMLLIElement
 ┃  ┗ Text "2番目"
 ┗ HTMLLIElement
    ┗ Text "3番目"
```

`HTMLLIElement`をコンソールに表示すると、タグ付きの文字列に見えますが、`children[n]`が文字列というわけではありません。

現実的には、HTML文書をJavaScriptから操作するときは `HTMLUListElement` `HTMLLIElement` などの `Element` を扱うことが多くなります。IDやclassを付けられるのが`Element`だけだからです。